# php5: How to create forms and input the form entry into mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

In php5 I just need to create a form where user can enter abc, def etc, this user entry should go to mysql query and display information, how this can be done?

Comment: So so so many tutorials on this. Google is your friend.

Comment: "how this can be done" --- it can be done easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this website can help you doing what you looking for and you can continue then: 
http://blazonry.com/scripting/linksdb/insert_data.php